# Mapping entity id to column in table with different name

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

The column name in database table is:  "aID" , but on my entity class the property name is Id.

I've tried this without success in my mapping class:

```
public AppMap()
{
   Id(app => app.Id).Column("aID");
}
```

Exception i get when trying to get all dads from database: Unable to resolve property:  Id

**In my entity class:**

```
    private int _id;
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
```

**Table in db:**

[image]

Column aID is auto increment in database.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem most probably lies elsewhere. The snippet you've shown is correct, and matches the [documentation](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping). Perhaps add some more details.

Comment: updated question with more information now.

Comment: What other properties are you mapping in your class? Is it possible the 'Id' it is referring to belongs to a collection/component property?

Comment: No, this is auto increment in db. Btw, The error occur when i try to get all dads.

Comment: The above code is working fine for me using Fluent NHibernate 1.2.0.712 and SQL Server 2008R2. Could you post the complete code for the entity class and the ClassMap?